# DB Select - Logic Meltdown

Tags: sql, database

I've been struggling with this one for a while.
[sample table]

```
ITEM  GROUP
----  -----
4     A
7     A
3     A
8     A
7     B
6     B
9     B
0     C
4     C
2     C
5     C
4     C
7     C
5     D
9     D
2     E
7     E
1     E
4     E
7     F
3     F
9     F
6     F
8     G
4     H
5     H
3     H
9     H
0     H
8     H
```

I need an sql query that will tell me how many times each "ITEM", on a range of SELECT DISTINCT ITEM appeared with one another in a particular group.

IE: 
Items 4 and 8 appeared 2 times (groups A and H). 
Items 0 and 4 appeared 2 times (groups C and H). 
Items 7, 6 and 9 appeared appeared 2 times (groups B and F).
..And do on.  It's ok to ignore "rogue" items that only appear in one group.

Can it be done?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for pairs of items:

```
SELECT T1.item, T2.item, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable T1
JOIN yourTable T2
ON T1.item < T2.item
AND T1.group = T2.group
GROUP BY T1.item, T2.item
```

Comment: This is going to over count when the same ID appears twice in the same group (for example, item 4 appears twice in group C). Of course, the OP doesn't explain how that should be counted, so maybe that will be right anyway. With that apparent duplicate it's not even clear if there are additional columns in the table to make rows unique or if it's just a heap.

Comment: @Tom H.: Good point, I hadn't noticed that. One possible fix is to create a view `SELECT DISTINCT item, group FROM yourTable` and use that view in the above query.